# How to get values from json field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `testtable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` json DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The json field has data that looks like this:

```
{'a1': 'Title', 'b17': 'Message'}
```

I want to select id and a1(json). I don't want b17. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL 5.7.8 or newer, you can take advantage of the JSON data type supported there:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

You can then use JSON Path expressions to extract values from the field.

Otherwise, you are stuck with either extracting the value through SUBSTR() and POSITION() functions - hokey example below - assuming the formatting of the values is sufficiently predictable, or else processing the result outside of SQL.

```
SELECT id, SUBSTR(hackedJSON, 1, POSITION("'" IN hackedJSON) - 1) a1
  FROM (
        SELECT id, SUBSTR(data, POSITION("'a1':" IN data) + 7) hackedJSON
          FROM testtable) a
```